# ¿Comprobar si existe o no el valor del atributo de un JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

**Al comprobar si existen los siguientes valores para el atributo "propertyName", quiero que si no existe me lo muestre**. Pero el problema está en que **me saca valores repetidos**, tantas veces como objErrList.length hay.
Si encuentra valor, no se repite, pero si no lo encuentra repite todo el listado, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Podéis ejecutar el código para ver lo que ocurre

```js
var errorList = '[{"propertyName":"nombre","error":"wrong"},{"propertyName":"direccion","error":"wrong"},{"propertyName":"email","error":"right"}]';

var objErrList = JSON.parse(errorList);

for(var j = 0; j < objErrList.length; j++) {

    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "email") {
        console.log("existe email");
    }
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "nombre") {
        console.log("existe nombre");
    }
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "ciudad") {
        console.log("existe ciudad");
    } else {
    console.log("no existe ciudad");
    }
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "dni") {
        console.log("existe dni");
    } else {
    console.log("no existe dni");
    }
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "pais") {
        console.log("existe pais");
    } else {
    console.log("no existe pais");
    }
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "provincia") {
        console.log("existe provincia");
    } else {
    console.log("no existe provincia");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola norak, no veo el problema por ningún lado. Simpemente estar diciendo si hay email, muestralo, si hay nombre muestralo, si hay ciudad muestralo, si no muestrame que no hay ciudad y así hasta el final. Si te fijas escribe un cosole log despues de los if para separar visualmente los registros

Comment: El problema es que cuando encuentre que "no existe ciudad" ya no repita esto más. Había pensado en un boolean pero ten en cuenta que en el caso real hay cientos de registros (he reducido el ejemplo para que se entienda). Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: um.. vale, no lo había pillado no lo querías hacer una vez por registro. vale vale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear un array con las propiedades a buscar y comprobar si existe algún elemento con ese nombre de propiedad:

```js
var errorList = '[{"propertyName":"nombre","error":"wrong"},{"propertyName":"direccion","error":"wrong"},{"propertyName":"email","error":"right"}]';

var objErrList = JSON.parse(errorList);

var properties = ['email', 'nombre', 'ciudad', 'dni', 'pais', 'provincia'];

for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
  console.log(
    (objErrList.find(function(x) {return x.propertyName===properties[j];}) ? '' : 'no ') +
    'existe ' + properties[j]
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Un genio! Es justo lo que estaba buscando, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!